# Pass value thought switch case php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, switch-statement, meta-boxes

HI I'm making a metabox plug for wordpress and get a problem:

when getting the info from the meta box (metabox has a text area and a radio) I use:

```
foreach ($rian_meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
switch ($field['type']) {

        case 'radio':

                    *some code, get the radio value and put in a variable $aaa*

        break;


        case 'textarea':

                    *some code, and after I should use the $aaa variable with his value  of the radio case*

                    break;
```

I tried but in the textarea case the variable is empty how I should do to pass it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly know the scenario in which you are trying to implement this but 'switch-case' is a bad idea for this.

I see you assign value to $aaa under case radio - but then there is a break statement which breaks out of the switch case loop, so the textarea case never gets executed.

simply try 'if-then' statement

if (val of radio button is something) 
then 
$aaa = something;
textarea value = $aaaa;

HTH

Comment: Sorry but in this way it doesn't work, I tried before and after your comment.I don't need to get a different value of the variable, I need to get the value in radio case and use it in the text area link